# Audio stream relay with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to develop an audio stream relay using [em-proxy](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-proxy).

Things like authentication and logging work out pretty well. The issue is that, every new incoming connection leads to a new connection to the audio stream.

A partial of my code:

```
require 'em-proxy'

host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 9889
puts "listening on #{host}:#{port}..."

Proxy.start(:host => host, :port => port) do |conn|

  conn.server :srv, host: "127.0.0.1", port: 8000

  conn.on_data do |data|
    # logging happens here
    data
  end

  conn.on_finish do |backend, name|
    # logging too
    unbind
  end

end
```

Ideally, I would like to have only one connection to the audio stream.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show some code of what is going on? The question is not clear.

Comment: Oh sorry for that @GuilhermeBernal. Just pasted some of the code. Thanks for looking into that.

Comment: You are trying to duplicate the outgoing data from port 8000?

Comment: I don't have practical experience with em-proxy, but it looks like it is tailored for relaying connections, not a one-way datastream. TCP is a two-way street, so it makes good sense that em-proxy should be creating new connections to the source, each time a client connects to the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `em-proxy`, but I did do a project in EventMachine a year ago.

What you want to do is connect to your audio stream when launching your proxy process. In addition to that, you will maintain a pool of clients. Each time data is received from the audio stream, you will iterate over your pool of clients and relay the received data.

Here is an EventMachine template:

```
module MyRadioClient
  def post_init
    some_client_list.add(self)
  end

  def receive_data data
    # do nothing        
  end

  def unbind
    some_client_list.remove(self)
  end
end
```

You'll launch the module with

```
EventMachine.run {
  EventMachine.start_server "0.0.0.0", 4567, MyRadioClient
}
```

Now people can connect on port 4567 and you will ignore anything they send.

Next, you'll need a connection to your audio stream, which - upon receiving data - will relay it to your radio clients.

You can see an example on it on page 20 in this document: http://everburning.com/images/2009/02/eventmachine_introduction_10.pdf

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Thank you @NielsB. for your answer.